# Remove multiple date fields in syslog filter

Tags: logstash, logstash-configuration

I have set up logstash and am using the "default" syslog filter as follows:

```
filter {
  if [type] == "syslog" {
    grok {
      match => { "message" => "%{SYSLOGTIMESTAMP:syslog_timestamp} %{SYSLOGHOST:syslog_hostname} %{DATA:syslog_program}(?:\[%{POSINT:syslog_pid}\])?: %{GREEDYDATA:syslog_message}" }
    }
    syslog_pri { }
    date {
      match => [ "syslog_timestamp", "MMM  d HH:mm:ss", "MMM dd HH:mm:ss" ]
    }
  }
}
```

This results in two fields being created, `@timestamp` and `syslog_timestamp` which essentially contain the same value, albeit in different formats.

Is there a way to create a temporary `syslog_timestamp` field in grok so it can be passed into the date plugin, or do I have to explicitly remove the field via mutate after I've "used" it? For example:

```
filter {
  if [type] == "syslog" {
    grok {
      match => { "message" => "%{SYSLOGTIMESTAMP:syslog_timestamp} %{SYSLOGHOST:syslog_hostname} %{DATA:syslog_program}(?:\[%{POSINT:syslog_pid}\])?: %{GREEDYDATA:syslog_message}" }
    }
    syslog_pri { }
    date {
      match => [ "syslog_timestamp", "MMM  d HH:mm:ss", "MMM dd HH:mm:ss" ]
    }
    mutate {
        remove_field => [ "syslog_timestamp" ]
    }
  }
}
```

Thanks for any pointers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are not really temporary fields, if you don't want `syslog_timestamp` you'll have to remove it.

One thing I advise though is that you perform the `remove_field` [in your date filter](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-filters-date.html#plugins-filters-date-remove_field). Doing this will only remove the field when the date filter is successfully applied, meaning that if the date filter fails, it will leave the `syslog_timestamp` field behind, potentially revealing the cause of the failure.

```
date {
  match => [ "syslog_timestamp", "MMM  d HH:mm:ss", "MMM dd HH:mm:ss" ]
  remove_field => [ "syslog_timestamp" ]
}
```